# How to securely set session variables for logging someone in?

Tags: php, security, session, session-variables

I have a few questions here if anyone can help me out. First off, I am in the process of creating a login system for users of my application. I am using shared hosting (dreamhost), and I am wondering, after the user logs in and it is successful, how can i verify if the user is logged in on pages? I am assuming that i use session variables, but the user's name needs to be stored for certain purposes. Is it safe to store the user's name in a session variable, and is it secure to basically just store if the user is logged in, into a session variable: ex: $_SESSION['logged'] = 1; or whatever. Also, I have been reading that anyone can access my session data since I am on shared hosting, and so should that be changed? Or should i just use something other than session variables all together?

Comment: would it be more secure to use CURL?

Comment: sure, to use CURL would be way more secure

Comment: I can't find too much documentation on cURL, but i thinki have found enough to write soemthing, but my question is, after the cURL function has been complete and everythign is verified, how can i use the rusults like i would a session variable, such as if($_SESSION['logged']){ VIEW WHATEVER CONTENT } else{ VIEW RESTRICTED CONTENT}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default session storage configuration will probably use a location shared between all the users on your shared hosting.  To verify this, take a look at the output of [phpinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php), in particular the `session.save_path` and `session.save_handler`.  These settings are documented in the [PHP session configuration documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php).

Your shared hosting may run your PHP processes as your user, as opposed to a system user.  In that case, you can change `session.save_path` to a directory in your home directory that is owned by you, and has permissions that prevent other users from reading that directory (700, for example).

If your shared hosting runs as a system user, you basically can't get a secure way to store those files.  You can then use a database-backed session storage option instead set with [session_set_save_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) - although I'm not sure how you could prevent others from reading your configuration settings.