# Authenticate users using cURL for my login system on my site?

Tags: php, curl, session-variables, login-control

Maybe I don't understand cURL, so I'll ask. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am currently attempting to create a login system for my site. I am under the impression that using cURL is much more secure. So, I was wondering how i can restrict access and grant access to data depending on if the user is logged in like how you would with session variables such as:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged'])){ SHOW CERTAIN DATA } else {SHOW DIFFERENT DATA}
```

Comment: Your `if` is basically ok. You will set the `$_SESSION['logged']` variable after the user successfully logs in, and then check it. I'm not sure what you need cURL for. cURL is for your site to interact with remote sites.

Comment: I just noticed this is a followup of sorts to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477311/how-to-securely-set-session-variables-for-logging-someone-in - I think you shouldn't worry about cURL for your login system. How were you planning on using it anyway?

Comment: ok, so i guess i didn't understand cURL, so by creating my own login system for my web site, i need to use session variables to control what the users can and cannot do?

Comment: just trying to create a login system, for the sake of learning, but i think i am spreading myself a bit too thin here, new information keeps popping up around every corner. I guess i needed an explanation of what cURL could do first. I thought you could use it for your own login system, but thats not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mistaken, cURL is not relevant to your problem. Just go ahead and use [sessions](http://php.net/session).

cURL is a library to do HTTP requests, like a programmable "web browser" in itself. It's useful for fetching external resources from other servers, but it's not relevant for an authentication system. cURL is not a web server, it's a web browser.